# what is the default timezone in Websphere 6.1

Tags: timezone, websphere

am running websphere 6.1 on RSA what is the default timezone set on it if i dont set any websphere variable etc(like the TZ variable).
Running into this weird issue where my application shows timestamp correctly for User timezone ,when i run it from my dev env but pulls out all timestamps in GMT irrespective of the logged in users timezone in an env which is supposed to have the server run on GMT.

So wanted to know what was the default TZ set if you do not configure anything

Comment: Please notice the dkpadhy's provided answer. It is correct for all IBM JDKs.

Answer (score 1):

it depends upon the locale where the server is installed. default locale time zone will be set to the server and the time zone can also be changed
Ex: for Webspher 7 please follow the link
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/trun_svr_timezones.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).